# Problem with Understanding Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to solve this exercise that asks to determine whether a language is regular or not.

Following the flow of the course I figured that the exercise is a test for Pumping Lemma application. But for this particular language I'm having a problem understanding where I'm at fault.

The language given is $L_3 = \{1^{2k+1}0^{2j} | k\geq 1 \text{ and } j\geq 0 \} $.

I began by assuming there's a DFA with n states that reads $L_3$, let that number of states be n. Then, for any $z\in L_3$ with a length $\geq n$ the PL should apply.

Let $z=1^{2n+1}0^{2j} \text{, } 2n+1+2j > n $.

Then z would be:

$$z=1...10...0=1...11...11...0$$

where $u=1...1=1^a$, $v=1...1=1^b$ and $w=1...0$ with their respective lengths for which $a+b\leq n$ and $|w|=2n+1+2j-a-b$ are true.

Then I can take any $uv^iw$ :

$$uv^iw= 1^a1^{ib}1^{2n+1-a-b}0^{2j}= 1^{a+ib+2n+1-a-b}0^{2j}= 1^{2n+1+b(i-1)}0^{2j}$$

Let's take i=2, then:

$$uv^2w=1^{2n+b+1}0^{2j}$$

But for any b that is odd $uv^2w \notin L_3$$.

However, considering the definition of a regular language I decided to make sure by trying to find a DFA for it; and I did. I found a DFA with 7 states that reads it. I'm quite sure that my DFA is okay, so I'm definitely making a mistake with my method above. What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language considered is indeed regular, since it can be expressed as a regular expression $111(11)^*(00)^*$.

Your mistake is that in the decomposition $z = 1^a1^bw$, you CANNOT chose $b$ to be odd. The pumping lemma states:

> If $L$ is regular, then there exists $n\geqslant 0$ such that for any $z\in \Sigma^*$, $|z| \geqslant n$, there exists a decomposition $z = uvw$ such that
>
> - $|uv| \leq n$;
> - $|v| > 0$;
> - for all $i\geqslant 0$, $uv^iw \in L$

However, you cannot chose the decomposition yourself, you just know that there exists one. In this particular language, any decomposition $uvw$ of $z = 1^{2n+1}0^{2j}$ will be such that $|v|$ is even.

Comment: Oh! I get it now! Thank you!